# How many sum of repeatable combinations of length N?

Tags: math, combinations, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

How many sum of repeatable combinations of length N ?

Like [1,3,5,10], N = 4.

And there gonna be

```py
[1,1,1,1] -> sum is 4

[1,1,1,3] -> sum is 6

...

[10,10,10,10] -> sum is 40
```

I perform a backtracking algo. by python3

```py
res = set()
n = 4
def backtrack(k, path):
    if len(path) == n:
        res.add(sum(path))
        return
    backtrack(k+1, path+[1])
    backtrack(k+1, path+[3])
    backtrack(k+1, path+[5])
    backtrack(k+1, path+[10])
    return
backtrack(0, list())
```

Is there has more efficient solution?

Comment: That is Python, isn't it? Consider tagging it to attract more potetially helpful users.

Answer (score 1):

If `n elements` order be not important, then your code is wrong
for example [1,1,2,2] ~ [1,2,1,2]

You can create a new list and repeat each element of the original `n` times. then the question is `how many ways we can select n item from new list` which can be calculated easily
further more if you want the result set of all the `sums` i think there's no better way than iterating in all situations.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But there is a set() for res, and I want to calculate the sum of combination in length of N (the order is not important)

Comment: Just like play N round game, each round can get the point 1, 3, 5, 10 randomly, and how many result will you finally get?

Comment: My question is, is there any other method besides backtracking?

Comment: Because in these case, the time complexity will be exponential.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n*len(list)*numberofdistinctsums)` approach.

We have two sets containing current possible sums for odd and even steps.
We calculate new sums formed with `i+1` summands from previous step sums (with `i` summands).

For example, after two rounds we have all possible sums of two summands. Getting sum `8` from previous set, we put sums of three summands `8+1, 8+3,8+5, 8+10` into new set and so on.

```
a = [1,3,5,10]
n = 4
sums = [set(a), set()]
for i in range(1, n):
    sums[i%2].clear
    for j in sums[(i+1)%2]:
        for x in a:
            sums[i%2].add(j + x)

print(len(sums[(n-1)%2]))
```

Comment: What is the usage of mod 2?

Comment: @Obito Kang To trigger between two sets - one for even steps, another for odd steps

Comment: So we get new sums (with i+1 summands) from previous step sums (with i summands)

Comment: Because the length will be N, so the lower bound of the sum should be [1,1,1,...,1] == N, and upper bound will be [10,10,10,...,10] == 10*N

Comment: Where was no 10 limit in the question. Having so small limitation, we can also use array(list) instead of  sets, but run time remains close. (I corrected time estimation for set approach in the answer)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.